# Diff to actually totally ignore whitespace

Tags: linux, windows, diff

I am looking for an application that will diff two files, and actually ignore all whitespace, so for example:

```
class foo { 
  bar
  spaz 
}
```

is equally equivilant to

```
class foo{bar spaz}
```

or, as well

```
classfoo { 
  barspaz}
```

but NOT

```
classfoo { 
  spazspaz
}
```

i.e. it would show me that `spaz` in the previous example has taken the place of `bar` in any of the other examples.  It only needs to compare 2 files.

- It can be a windows or linux/unix/posix-compatible utility
- I've tried the lin/unix `diff -w` command, it only ignores whitespace if the difference *per-line* is whitespace.  I don't see an option to *totally* ignore whitespace.
- I also tried UECompare or Ultracompare, a non-free comparison utility for windows.

Comment: By design, `diff` compares files line by line. The newlines serve as delimiters for the changes. Without them it would be hard to do a meaningful comparison. shurane's answer would work, but it is less than useful for the reason set out in the comments.

Comment: How the heck in any programming language is "barspaz" the same as "bar spaz"?  Very strange.

Comment: You could replace all whitespace with linebreaks, then `diff` the results. That would generate lots of lines of output for large chunks of differences, though. I think you'd need a new program (or a `diff` flag) to compare files without treating linebreaks specially.

Comment: This question has a [possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/639981/diff-ignoring-eol-and-whitespace).

Comment: Try wdiff too. It's not line-based like diff, so it manages your first equivalence (though not your second).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the `tr` command? Here are the [manpages](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tr+1). It's included with `msysgit`, `cygwin`, and `gnuwin32 tools` as far as I can tell.

So you can remove all the whitespace prior to diffing by doing something like:

```
tr --delete '[:space:]' <filename.txt
```

You can then feed the output of that command to `diff` and have it work without having any whitespace.

For example, I have a file named `HelloWorldApp.java`. Let me show you how `tr` processes it:

```
C:\temp>cat HelloWorldApp.java
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
C:\temp>tr -d '[:space:]' <HelloWorldApp.java
classHelloWorldApp{publicstaticvoidmain(String[]args){System.out.println("HelloWorld!");//Displaythestring.}}
```

Comment: The problem with this is it gives you a single line of everything mashed together. If you tried to feed that into `diff`, `diff` would tell you that each file has one line, and the lines are different. Not very helpful.

Comment: @BlacklightShining Well, yes, but that *is* what the question asked for...

Comment: @BlacklightShining Presumably the OP will be working with very short files where there is a chance of them matching up after the whitespace is removed. I can't think of a specific task where this would be useful... but then that's the point of having these modular \*nix commands: so that they can be used together for niche tasks that most people would never think of.

Comment: Essentially I am trying to compare two pieces of CSS, one has been *partially* minified (e.g. some rules are in one line), the other has not.  They contain about 90% of the same rules.  I think I'm just going to write a custom parser.

Comment: To get a bit more meaningful output, instead of deleting all whitespace, try replacing whitespace with a newline first: `tr '[:space:]' '\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Despite being line oriented, diff *could* be made to do what's being
requested. Roughly, you could do the diff -w and then post process the
diff output. It could look at the diff output and join various pairs of lines
to see if they (now) match the line in the other file.

Seems like it might be O(n^2) or other nasty thing, but it would still
be very helpful if it limited it self to (say) no join, join 2 lines, join 3 lines on file 1
X no join, join 2 lines, join 3 lines on file 2 on a moving "window" of the diff output.
(where X is ~ "cross product")

In fact, seems like a job that a Perl diff output post-processing script could do with
few hours of work (depending on your (Perl) programming skill)

Maybe when I have some task that I don't really want to be doing at work ... :-)